# git status vs fetch (or pull): How to know what "up-to-date" means (without changing anything)

Tags: git

I do a `git status` and it says
`Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.`

But I do a `git pull` anyway and suddenly it says
`14 files changed, ...`

And I feel like I've been lied to. I suspect git isn't broken. Which must mean I don't understand something.

I do a bit of reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938723/git-how-to-check-if-a-local-repo-is-up-to-date) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212603/git-checkout-and-git-status-both-say-i-am-up-to-date-but-then-git-pull-pulls-ch) and learn of two non destructive ways to ask if I'm up to date

`git status -uno`

`git fetch --dry-run`

Since `fetch` is part of `pull` I assume these two will disagree the same way the last two did.

What's fundamentally confusing me is I think of 'up-to-date' as meaning: "hey we've compared two copies of this repository (the master branch) and they're the same"

Ok fine, but if I can ask the question two different ways and get two different answers, when each question is about comparing two different copies then doesn't that mean there have to be at least three copies of the repository?

As in:

> A == B != C

I know there is a remote copy of master
I know there is my local copy of master

What the heck is this third thing?

Comment: What you want is to run `git fetch` *first*, so that your local repository has its remote-tracking branches updated to match the branches on the remote (so that they're current instead of from literally days or even, gasp, *seconds* ago, how ancient! :-) ).  Then `git status` can compare your current branch (eg `master`) against whatever you have set as its upstream (`origin/master`).  Note that `git pull` is `git fetch` followed by `git merge`, but what you want is `git fetch` first, followed by `git status` second, followed *maybe* by `git merge` or `git rebase` last.

Comment: You're saying I should think of `git fetch` as being non destructive since the tracking branch is supposed to model the remote branch at all times.  The fact that it's sometimes outdated is just a mechanical issue.  In a perfect world it would always be up to date?

Comment: Yes, `git fetch` is basically nondestructive.  There's one corner (or side?) case: suppose that you have local repo L with remote R, and you run `git fetch` and pick up R/foo, which whoever pushes to R put on R by mistake: it's supposed to be released next week, not now.  Then they retract or delete foo on R.  If you re-fetch (with --prune, or they've simply retracted rather than deleting), your R/foo is retracted or deleted and now you no longer have their mistake.  But if you missed the window of accidental publishing, you don't get that R/foo in the first place.

Comment: I'll also note that if you log *all* ref updates, including remote-tracking branches, you will retain their accidentally published commits in your R/foo reflogs.  It's only when they really delete R/foo (and you're using --prune) that you lose stuff you were not supposed to have in the first place.  (Logging of all ref updates defaults to "on".)

Comment: @torek so while not totally nondestructive it would only ever destroy things other people have already deliberately requested be destroyed.

Comment: Not to answer your question, you could run `git ls-remote <remote> | grep master$` to check the current last commit of the remote master.

Answer (score 6):

When Git says `Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'` it is comparing your local `master` branch against the *remote tracking* branch called `origin/master`.  This tracking branch also exists locally and is what is actually used when you update your local branch.  And when you do a `git fetch`, all the remote tracking branches get updated.

Your local `master` branch was current with the tracking branch, but this does not mean that the local branch is current with the actual `master` branch on the repository.  Had you done a `git fetch` after your initial call to `git status`, you would have a seen a message saying that your local `master` branch was "behind" `origin/master`.  Doing a `git pull` means updating the tracking branch `origin/master`, and then merging that into your local branch to sync everything.

Here is a simplistic diagram showing the flow of information from the remote to your local branch:

```
remote master (repo) --> origin/master (local tracking branch) --> master (local branch)
```

Comment: So the third thing is the local tracking branch? That's not what I code in?  Does that exist on my box somewhere that I could go look at it?

Comment: I'm not sure what third refers to in your mind, but the local (remote) tracking branch is what is somewhat hidden.  This is the source of your confusion, because Git locally uses it to report on the status of branch, e.g. whether it is ahead or behind.  And the tracking branch is what _tracks_ the changes on the actual repository, via doing a `git fetch`.

Comment: Ok so `git fetch --dry-run` will show me differences around your leftmost arrow.  `git status -uno` will show me differences around your rightmost arrow.  I got that right?

Comment: `git fetch --dry-run` just shows what the fetch would do, which is between the leftmost arrow, but `git status -uno` shows changes in your working directory minus untracked files.

Comment: By 'working directory' do you mean what you previously labeled 'master (local branch)' or is this some 4th thing?

Comment: Yes, working directory just refers to a diff of your local branch when you last committed and the changes you have made since.  It does not involve the other two branches in my diagram.

Comment: Wait, so `git status -uno` won't show differences between the 'local tracking branch' and the 'local branch'? Why does it talk about being up-to-date with 'origin/master' then?  I thought commits were going to 'origin/master' when they were committed, without needing a `git push`.

Comment: To clarify after the rant:
The "remote tracking branch" is actually a *local* branch but it tracks the remote origin.
The local "remote tracking branch" doesn't keep itself automatically up to date, that's what `git fetch` is for.
So `git status` compares one local branch with the local (old) "remote tracking branch" and finds it's "up to date".
Then a `git fetch` brings down the remote origin changes into the local "remote tracking branch" and `git status` can now report differences.

Answer (score 3):

To add a bit<sup>1</sup> to [Tim Biegeleisen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37694631/1256452), `git status` works by performing *two* diffs *plus* also comparing your current `HEAD` to its upstream.

Here's the complete(...ish) picture.

Given a remote repository *R*, `git fetch` copies from every branch it sees on `R`—you can see what it sees by running `git ls-remote R`—and renames them in the process.  For branches *B1*, *B2*, and *B3*, your Git creates or updates remote-tracking branches *R/B1*, *R/B2*, and *R/B3*.  (More precisely, these are references whose name starts with `refs/remotes/` and then continues on to name the same remote *R*, e.g., `origin/`, and then the branch name.  This guarantees that these references never collide with your own local branches, which start with `refs/heads/`: your master is `refs/heads/master` while that copied from remote `origin` is `refs/remotes/origin/master`.

(Your Git may also bring over tags, depending on flags you give to `git fetch`.  The default is slightly complicated: it brings over tags for any commits it brings over while bringing over branches.  With `--no-tags` it skips tags entirely, and with `--tags` it brings over all tags.  Tags, unlike branches, do not have special per-remote name spaces: your tag `T1` is really `refs/tags/T1`, and if your Git brings over a tag `T2` from remote *R*, it just names it `refs/tags/T2`.  If two tags collide, your Git defaults to ignoring the extra one, i.e., if you already have a `T2`, your Git drops *their* `T2` on the floor.<sup>2</sup>)

In order to bring over these branches (and maybe tags), your Git must bring over the commits (and any other objects) they point-to, as identified by the SHA-1 hashes you will see in that same `git ls-remote` output.  To get a commit, your Git has to get any trees and blobs to which that commit object points.  Your Git and their Git therefore have a conversation, leading to the object counting and compressing and so on that you see: your Git already has some set of objects and yours and theirs simply work to see what you have in common, to determine how best to get you the ones you don't have yet.

All of these objects get inserted into your repository.  At this point, they are pointed-to by your remote-tracking branches, such as `origin/master`.  If you now run `git status`, it can—and does—work entirely locally.

Let's say you're on your own `master`.  In this case, your `HEAD` reference simply contains the string `ref: refs/heads/master`.<sup>3</sup>  This is in fact *how* Git knows that you are on branch `master`.  Meanwhile, Git stores, under `.git/config`, some extra data to record that your local `master` has `origin/master` (really `refs/remotes/origin/master`; Git just abbreviates a lot) as its *upstream*.

So, `git status` discovers that you are on `master` and also looks up `origin/master`.  These two names—`refs/heads/master` and `refs/remotes/origin/master`—point to two commit IDs.  Those commit IDs may be the same, or may be different.  If they are the same, the two branches are in sync.  If they differ, the two branches differ.  One may contain more commits than the other—so that one is strictly ahead and the other strictly behind—or they may have some commits that are different on both branches, and some commits that are common to both.

(This is where Git's terminology breaks down: does "branch" mean "branch *name*", like `master`?  Or does it mean "the set of all commits reachable by starting at the branch's tip-most commit and working back through history"?  The answer is that it means *both*, and we are supposed to figure out which meaning to use.)

To get the `ahead 3` and/or `behind 5` count, `git status` uses `git rev-list --count`:

```
git rev-list --count origin/master..master
git rev-list --count master..origin/master
```

This two-dot syntax means "find the set of all commits reachable from the identifier on the right, and subtract away the set of all commits reachable from the identifier on the left".  Suppose, for instance, `master` is strictly ahead of `origin/master`.  We can draw the commit chain like this:

```
... <- o <- o <- o     <-- origin/master
                  \
                   o   <-- master
```

Here there is one commit on `master` that is not on `origin/master`.  All commits on `origin/master` are on *both* branches: both the local branch and the remote-tracking branch.  But there is one commit on `master` that is not on `origin/master`.

When `git fetch` obtains new commits, those new commits normally point back to existing commits.  So if `git fetch` picks up one new commit on `origin/master`, the picture changes:

```
... <- o <- o <- o <- o  <-- origin/master
                  \
                   o   <-- master
```

Now neither branch is strictly behind, and you will probably want to merge or rebase your work.

---

Meanwhile, `git status` *also* compares:

- your index/staging-area to your `HEAD` commit
- your work-tree to your staging-area

The (single, distinguished) index contains the set of all files that will go into the *next* commit you can make.  When you `git add` new contents for existing files, this replaces the existing file in the staging area.  (Strictly speaking, the index contains only the *hash*, plus necessary stuff like the file's path, plus a bunch of cache information to speed up `git status` and `git commit`.  The `add` step actually copies the file into the repository, computing its hash, at `add` time, and stores the new hash into the index.)  Adding a totally new file adds a new entry, and removing an existing file with `git rm` adds a special "erase" or "white-out" entry so that Git knows not to put that file into the *next* commit.

When `git status` shows you what is staged for commit, it does so by diff-ing the index against `HEAD`.

When `git status` shows you what is *not* staged for commit, but *could* be, it does so by diffing the work-tree against the index.

---

<sup>1</sup>OK, a lot.

<sup>2</sup>In a bug in pre-1.8.4 or so versions of Git, tags could change as long as they moved in a fast-forward manner, which is the same rule applied by default during `git push`.  I think this did not happen on `fetch` though.

<sup>3</sup>`HEAD` is a reference, just like `refs/heads/master` and `refs/remotes/origin/master`, but with some special handling.  In particular, `HEAD` is normally an *indirect* reference, with that `ref:` prefix stuff.  While any reference can be indirect, `HEAD` is the only *useful* indirect, at least currently (Git version 2.8.x).  Furthermore the only useful indirect values are to regular local branches.  When `HEAD` contains the name of a local branch, `git status` says that you are "on" that branch.

Checking out a commit by its SHA-1 hash ID, or using `--detach`, puts the raw ID into `HEAD`.  In this case `git status` claims that you are not on any branch.  In fact, you are on the (single) anonymous branch: new commits you make go into the repository as usual, but are known only by the special name `HEAD`, and if you check out some other branch, the IDs of those commits become somewhat difficult to retrieve.  (They're still stored in the reflog for `HEAD`, until those reflog entries expire; after that point, they are eligible for being garbage-collected by `git gc`.)

Comment: While I think I'm getting more wet than hydrated from this firehose I will say this line: 'does "branch" mean "branch name", like master? Or does it mean "the set of all commits..."' turned on a lightbulb for me.

Comment: Git is full of items that are, to use Ted Nelson's phrase, "deeply intertwingled": they make a lot more sense once you understand all the pieces but you can't understand the pieces until you understand the whole.  Or, it's like that scene from The Wizard of Speed and Time, when Mike Jittlov discovers that in order to join the union, you have to already be a member. :-)