# git status didn't show modified files

Tags: git, version-control

I created a branch, say 'new_branch' from the develop branch on bitbucket and from my local I switch to it

```
git checkout -b new_branch
```

After I git pull the code, I tried

```
git status
```

to see the modified files.

However from the output, I didn't see one file that I knew was modified, other modified files seemed OK.

For that particular file, say 'test.cs', I did

```
git diff origin/new_branch -- local-path/test.cs
```

and confirm the change, but how come wasn't it shown on the 'git status' output?

As a result I can't do add/commit/push the file in.

Can anyone help? Hope I made myself clear.

Comment: That isn't how Git works. `git status` shows you changes between your working directory and the commit you're on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you think is wrong.

Let's note here that `git status` reports a lot of things.  The information on specific files, such as `local-path/test.cs`, comes from *two* `git diff` commands, but *not* from the one you are running.

#### The index / staging-area

In a normal Git repository, there are *three* items of interest with regard to each file.  There is the file's state in your current (or `HEAD`) commit.  There is the file's state in your work-tree, where you can edit the file with your favorite editor(s), run any normal commands on it, and so on.  And, there is the file's state in Git's *index*, also called Git's "staging area".

The staging area is, in essence, "what will go into the next commit you make".  Remember that in Git, every commit is a *complete snapshot* of your work: every file that is staged (or "tracked", i.e., is not an "untracked file") is recorded exactly as it appears in the staging area.  Once you make the commit, the staging area matches the commit you just made.  It's not empty—it's full of files—but a `git diff` that *compares* the commit to the index *will* be empty, because the index and the commit contain the same stored-up work-tree.  If you then modify a file in the work tree and `git add` it, Git replaces the index version with the work-tree version, so that now the index and the `HEAD` commit differ.

#### `git status` and `git diff`

With that in mind, let's take a look at your specific `git diff` command, and [the `git diff` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html).  You ran:

> ```
> git diff origin/new_branch -- local-path/test.cs
> ```

The documentation says, in part:

> `git diff [--options] <commit> [--] [<path>...]`
>         This form is to view the changes you have in your working tree
>    relative to the named <commit>. You can use HEAD to compare it with
>    the latest commit, or a branch name to compare with the tip of a
>    different branch.

This means you were comparing the work-tree version of `local-path/test.cs` against the version in the commit at the tip of `origin/new_branch`.

The index version of the file has no part in this comparison.

Now let's look at what `git status` diffs.  These quotes are still from the `git diff` documentation:

> `git diff [--options] --cached [<commit>] [--] [<path>...]`
>          This form is to view the changes you staged for the next commit
>    relative to the named <commit>. Typically you would want comparison
>    with the latest commit, so if you do not give <commit>, it defaults
>    to HEAD. If HEAD does not exist (e.g. unborn branches) and <commit>
>    is not given, it shows all staged changes. --staged is a synonym of
>    --cached.

You can safely ignore the slightly odd notion of "unborn branch" here.  This compares a specific commit versus the index.  By default, it compares `HEAD` vs the index.  This tells you what would be different in a new commit.

This is the first diff that `git status` does, to find out what you would commit if you committed now.

We also find, in the `git diff` documentation, this:

> `git diff [--options] [--] [<path>...]`
>          This form is to view the changes you made relative to the index
>    (staging area for the next commit). In other words, the differences
>    are what you could tell Git to further add to the index but you
>    still haven't. You can stage these changes by using git-add(1).

In other words, this compares the index to the work-tree.  Whatever shows up as different here, you *could* `git add` to your index, so that it shows up in the *first* diff that `git status` runs.  Instead, it currently shows up in the *second* diff that `git status` runs.

After `git status` has run these two diffs, it prints any files that showed up in either one, as "changes staged for commit" or "changes not staged for commit"—or, in some cases, *both*.  (For instance, you can add a line to `README` and stage that, then add *another* line to `README` but not stage it yet.  Now you have changes from `HEAD` to index—the first line you added—*and* changes from index to work-tree: the second line you added.)

Again, `git status` reports all of these.  You say it is reporting nothing: **this means that your `HEAD` commit matches your index, and your index matches you work-tree.**  There is one special case to consider before we move on.

For untracked files—which are by definition not in the index and not in the `HEAD` commit—`git status` normally reports them as "untracked files".  This is often more annoying than useful, so you can use `.gitignore` to tell `git status` to shut up about these files.  Check your `.gitignore` to see if it is ignoring `local-path/test.cs`.  Presumably it is not, but if it is, that could be the reason you would not see anything.

#### Putting it all together

You also say that if you `git diff origin/new_branch -- local-path/test.cs`, you *do* see differences.  This means that your work-tree *does not* match the commit to which `origin/new_branch` points.

From `git status` (and assuming no `.gitignore` action), we know that the `HEAD` and work-tree versions of `local-path/test.cs` are the same.  And, we see that the `origin/new_branch` version of `local-path/test.cs` are different.  We can therefore conclude that the `HEAD` version is *not* the `origin/new_branch` version: these must be two different commits.

This is a perfectly normal state.  Sometimes `git status` does report something *else* for this state, though.

#### Upstream branches

Specifically, each branch can have an *upstream branch*.  No branch is *required* to have an upstream branch, and there is no constraint on the form of the upstream branch if there is one, but every branch *can* have one—and *only* one—upstream.

Normally, a local branch like `master` or `new_branch` *usually* has a remote-tracking branch like `origin/master` or `origin/new_branch` as its upstream.

The existence of the upstream is, again, optional.  But if there *is* one, `git status` uses it to compare the current branch against its upstream.

Specifically, if `new_branch` has `origin/new_branch` set as its upstream, and if—as we believe we have just proved—`new_branch` and `origin/new_branch` differ, `git status` will tell us that one branch is ahead of the other, or behind the other, or both.  (The `git status` command does this by comparing the commits—not their contents, just the commits themselves—that are reachable from the two branches.  I'm not going into any further detail here; for much more on this, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37696657/1256452).)

**None of this can happen unless the current branch has an upstream set.**

You wrote that you ran:

> ```
> git checkout -b new_branch
> ```

This form of `git checkout` creates a new branch, and by default, *does not set an upstream for it*.

To set an upstream, use `git branch --set-upstream-to` (see [the documentation for `git branch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html) for details).

Note that `git checkout name`, when *`name`* does not currently exist as a local branch, but `origin/name` *does* exist, will create the local branch *`name`* with its upstream set to `origin/name`.  This is very different from `git checkout -b`, which creates a local branch with *no* upstream set (and often a different starting value for the branch tip).